# Show that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n) = 1-\alpha^{-n(n+1)/2}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

[image: Question]

Here's my approach:-

$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n)=1-P(\overline A_1\cap\overline A_2\cap...\cap\overline A_n) $
=$1-\left[(1-\frac{1}{\alpha^1})(1-\frac{1}{\alpha^2})\ldots(1-\frac{1}{\alpha^n})\right]$
=$1-\left[(\frac{\alpha^1-1}{\alpha^1})(\frac{\alpha^2-1}{\alpha^2})\ldots(\frac{\alpha^n-1}{\alpha^n})\right]$
=$1-\left[\frac{(\alpha^1-1)(\alpha^2-1)(\alpha^3-1)\ldots (\alpha^n-1)}{\alpha^{n(n+1)/2}}\right]$

What should I do to proceed?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Try putting for instance, $n=2$ and $\alpha=7$. According to the problem, the answer should be $\frac{342}{343}$, but your approach results $\frac{55}{343}$.

Comment: You might want to use the [Inclusion-exlcusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid there is a typo in the exercise given.

For a counterexample, let $\alpha=2$, $n=2$, $P(A_1)=\frac12$, $P(A_2)=\frac14$. Then
$$P(A_1\cup A_2)\le P(A_1)+P(A_2)=\frac12+\frac14=\frac34$$
However, $$1-\alpha^{-n(n+1)/2}=1-2^{-2\cdot3/2}=\frac78>\frac34$$

---

The intended version of the exercise should have probably been as follows.

> (b) $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., $A_n$ are $n$ independent events with $P(\overline{A_i})=\frac1{\alpha^i}$; $i=1,2,..., n$. Show that
> $$P(A_1\cup A_2...\cup A_n)=1-\alpha^{-n(n+1)/2}$$

You have proved the version above, basically.